# Stop typescript generics inside Records from "intersecting" all the keys for nested generic records

Tags: typescript

I want the nested generic to know about the parent Record's key,
the desired behavior in the typesystem would work like this:

```js
let c = {
  "hey": {ext: `${parent.key === "hey"}` /*true*/},
  "bye": {ext: `${parent.key === "bye"}` /*true*/}
}
```

But the actual behavior is this:

```js
let c = {
  "hey": {ext: `${parent.key === "hey"}` /*false, parent.key === "hey" | "bye"*/},
  "bye": {ext: `${parent.key === "bye"}` /*false, parent.key === "hey" | "bye"*/}
}
```

How can I force typescript to only take the key that the object is defined under ?

Full Example
[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwiAtgB3AUzFCMC8MDeAsAFACQA6gE4CGyyalAXDABTWUDmz+MY1iaZtEoBLMBwDcMEADMAgh0G8ArogBGDGAF8AlLgB8BLQBoSpAELKoUcMzaduMaouZhVGylJnUAbiFFQaBBCUKLiANoAutp6OIb4JiRaEiQkaAAeqJSwUACe9PBIqGAYUAAyItC4MADkVLT0lDUwAD61ltbgNSnEaZn+OfloMADiaFAACpQgyBAAPAAqMBmBYAAm2Ago6JgV0IZ4E+z84wzzefSyhdslmBDhC5H64QAMkT0kF8NTMxAA0mhcvMlisMBtrsVSnsoAcYMIxBwYAAyGAAUXSwAANso1mg5gBrQFXMaTaazRb6Yy1YAACxEmLWlAwNX0H2IXxgiigAHlGtQbJRgct0qtwVtIbtKlAqQA5YWi7A-WYAoEU2EAAwAJPh4eJkWYZVoAHTa3WIlGE3LE8ZK4HPGWRLTqtkcsogDgiYCLeVgzZFHblKWyn3rRVk-6Au2wgBKaFAlDWcwNpjIRDIpBWzC5vIY-P8wNlrLMWhIRd6xFAkFgiFyADEwNVvaDQxCA9Dg83wbaVVGWGZMe7PcxY-HEwsqW6PV7xzAZfp9CRYvFkqliAB6Ncwbx+AJBGCVXggWDUCAQEQcPhqTHDGwwDk1SeeuYAIg6NjAz6pz+caGf+hqRokBu+6wAAqmAIjgNgUA0sMvjUPS1BXsMyBkgwUAiHuNhcrBlBUmoVgwAAkjAADuIDKAyMCYiIhIgXeIAwPiYAgKRd40vyW7+OxwwrDAyDsLA4CYrkW6+P4IiBNg3E-k4dA0UEJA1vWLBphYVjvtwZikD+jiZrUP5GjYADKoQIs0iTptuElSXpIrMDU1m7hARrXuIMEWSmpCWboPRAA)

```
const Components = {
    Wrapper: (arg: { name: string; ofAge: number }) => {},
    Button: (arg: { age: number; favorites: string[] }) => {},
};

export type ComponentList = 'Wrapper' | 'Button';

export type GetProps<T extends ComponentList> = Parameters<typeof Components[T]>[0];

type PropsKeys<T extends ComponentList> = string & Exclude<keyof GetProps<T>, 'children'>;

type getOperators<T extends ComponentList, N extends PropsKeys<T>> = `${string &
    N}.${string & keyof GetProps<T>[N]}`;

type Logic<T extends ComponentList, N extends PropsKeys<T>> = Record<
    N,
    {
        ext: getOperators<T, N>;
    }
>;

const myFn = <T extends ComponentList, N extends PropsKeys<T>>(
    logic: Record<T, Logic<T, N>>
) => {};

// favorites is not assignable to type 'Logic<"Button", "age">'.
// it Unions the available properties together, but I would like it to know that for the ext part only favorites or age applies
myFn({
    Button: {
        age: { ext: 'age.toString' },
        favorites: { ext: 'favorites.length' },
    },
});
```

Comment: Could you pare this down to a [mre]?  For instance: I don't see what `Exclude<..., "children">` is doing: if it's not relevant to the example, you should remove it so it's not distracting; if it *is* relevant then you should probably add stuff to the example to show why it's there.  It might be a good exercise for you to go through the whole code example with an eye on removing anything not directly relevant to demonstrating your issue.

Comment: Presumably you just need to make `Logic` a mapped type where the value type depends on each key type, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX7VOW).  `Record` is a utility type that only makes sense if the value type is the same for every key.  I'm happy to write up an answer, if you'll [edit] the example code here to make it as minimal as possible, perhaps like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mL4xvm)?  Let me know.